# Least squares solution of underdetermined system with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, least-squares

With $Ax=b$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 8}, x \in \mathbb{R}^{8 \times 1}$ I can find the least squares solution $x$ for a given $b$ such that I minimize $\left\|x\right\|^2_2$. The general least squares solution (According to my understanding) is given by $A^+b$ where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of $A$.

However I would like to find the least squares solution $x$ such that $x \geq 0$. And if it is possible, to find a general matrix $A'$ such that $A'b = x \geq 0$ ? Maybe the latter is impossible as the sign of $A'b$ depends on the sign of $b$ which in the problem I am considering is unconstrained.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the problem you're trying to solve is
\begin{aligned}
\min_{\mathbf{x}}\quad & \|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b}\|^2 \\
s.t. \quad & x_i\geq 0
\end{aligned}
This is known as [Non negative least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares) and can be solved using any convex optimization algorithm. In your case the problem is of small scale ($n=8$) so in general it's easy to solve. You can use a second order solver like [quadprog](https://github.com/quadprog/quadprog) or even a simple first order algorithm like Projected Gradient (with or without acceleration).

As for your last question, finding $A\,:\, A^T\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{x}\geq\mathbf{0}$, what is the reason for this requirement? I'm asking since it's different than the original question - where $A, \mathbf{b}$ are the given data (not a variables) and we look for $\mathbf{x}$ that best fits this data.

Comment: I want to get a state space representation of a spacecraft thruster allocation algorithm. Here $b$ is the desired angular impulse and $x$ is the array of thruster firing times hence the constraint $x_i \ge0$. Sounds like the SS representation isn’t really possible with this constraint where only $b$ is a variable, right?

Comment: @ThomasKirven honestly I have no clue what you just said :) What are your variables? Can you formulate an explicit problem?

Comment: sorry! lol I am used to talking with ppl in aerospace and assume everyone knows what the thruster allocation problem is :). Basically you have (in this case) 8 thrusters arranged on a spacecraft that each produce a constant torque vector and force vector (thanks to newtons 3rd law) relative to the spacecraft frame of reference.

Comment: So the problem is how to optimally allocate thruster firing durations $x_i$ to impart the desired momentum $b$ to the whole spacecraft. The momentum achieved by a single thruster is it’s torque*firing duration. The columns of A describe the torque each thruster produces. Since $x_i$ is time it must be positive (you cant fire a thruster for -6 seconds :D) The only variable is $b$ (the desired momentum for the whole spacecraft).

Comment: I think I have answered the second question for myself that there is no constant $A’$ matrix that will always minimize firing times for any given $b$. But your answer to my first question was really helpful @iarbel84, thanks!

Comment: I think your answer also answers my second question in that $A’$ must also be variable to solve the problem.